# Communication in multiple contacts network in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have defined a `Person` agent and a population of Person "living" inside `Main` agent environment. I'm wondering if in anylogic there is some kind of mechanism to define multiple layer networks and send messages only in specific layer, i.e I want to define for person agents some relations like "family connections" if agents are in the same family (see picture, each connected component is a family), "workplace connections" if agents works in the same place, etc. From the help guide I understood that is possible to create multiple [custom connections links](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/Link.html?cp=0_4_7_3).

What isn't clear to me is how to reference a specific relation when I send messages between agents, i.e **I would send messages from agent X only to the connected agents Y1,...,Y2 for the relation "family connections" ignoring connected agents for the relation "workplace connections"**.

From the api doc i see only methods like `getConnections()` (or [`send()`](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/javadoc/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html#send-java.lang.Object-com.anylogic.engine.Agent-)) to return all the connected agents without the possibility to specify the connection links object (aka a specific network layer).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a link to family members you can use the link to agents object, call it familyLink for instance and connect all your family together. You will have another independent workersLink.

you connect your agents by doing familyLink.connectTo(agent); where the agent is a person which is part of the family.

to send messages to all your family you can do:

```
familyLink.sendToAllConnected(msg);
```

Comment: The answer is pretty clear, but maybe doesn't solve my problem. I uploaded an example picture to clarify my intents, all the links are of "family relation" but i want to send only messages from specific agent, say "node 0", to the connected nodes (only intra connected components communication). With `sendToAllConnected(msg)` how I can pass as argument the agent witch start the communication? I'm searching for something like familyLink.sendToAllConnected(agent, msg). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the link connection mechanism? Maybe each Person agent should have a reference to a familyLink object?

Comment: you do agent.familyLink.sendToAllConnected(msg) where agebnt is the guy from the family who is sending the message... read more on link to agents... I don't know how to explain in more detail

Comment: Yes what I didn't realize is that connection link objects are attributes of the agent, thanks a lot, you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a paramter to define the layer of agents (like Person.layer = "XXX"), then make a filter on Persons that should receive the message:

for (Person p : populationOfPerson.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList())) {
/// send msg to p;
}

Comment: Sorry, but this seems a workaround rather than a proper Anylogic solution.